# Exporting SQL Table to .csv file shows NULL values

Tags: sql-server, csv, export-to-csv

I am using MS SQL Express 2012. I have saved my SELECT query result into csv file but there are some values which are exported as NULL.
I cross checked it in my table but there is no NULL value in the column.

I need help with this issue. Is it an exporting error by Management Studio or anything else.

Comment: Please post your query and an example of the database table...

Comment: I got a Solution. I saved the table as a tsv format. It worked.
Thanks

Comment: Post your answer and mark it as correct (i'm sure there's a badge for that!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+A the rows returned and right click to save as. Then here you can select csv or tsv format.